# Inner shadow have incorrect Color in Android 6-7

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

**Greetings to all**
I need assistance to solve the problem with shape, gradient. I use **theme** with parent ↓

```
<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge" />

<style name="Theme.Movie42" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

and i have a shape with gradient inside ↓

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="@color/center_of_shape"
            android:centerX="0.6"
            android:endColor="@color/end_of_shape"
            android:startColor="@color/start_of_shape"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I use it for make inner shadow on imageView↓

```
imageView.background =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(application.applicationContext, itemMovieData.drawable)
imageView.setImageDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            application.applicationContext,
            R.drawable.shape
        )
    )
```

When i run app on **Android 11** (*emulator*)  everyfing looks good
but when it runs on real device with **Android 6 or 7** (maybe else versions)
"inner shadow" have a white color which is i don't actually need↓
[image: bad and good]

How to fix this issue? Make shadow "great again", i mean make it dark on **api 23/24**↑

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Color **00FFFFFF** and **00000000** are not the same colors. Yes they both **100% transparent** and on screen looks the same. In android *6-7* it matters which of these colors do you chose.
So I chose the wrong color and make my shadow white. I am ashamed